# Python tkinter: input not equal to answer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code using `Tkinter`, `python` and get that when I answer correctly, it says that the answer is wrong:

```
    self.whatWord = StringVar()

    self.missingWordPrompt = Entry(root, textvariable=self.whatWord)
    self.missingWordPrompt.pack()

    #self.missingWordPrompt.bind('<Return>', self.checkWord())

    self.submitbutton = Button(root, text='Check Answer', command=self.checkWord)
    self.submitbutton.pack()

    '''self.answerLabel = Label(root, textvariable=self.missingWord)
    self.answerLabel.pack()'''

    self.answer = self.missingWord.get()

    print(self.answer)

def checkWord(self):
    self.my_input = self.missingWordPrompt.get()
    print(self.my_input)

    if str(self.answer).lower() == str(self.my_input).lower():
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('wrong answer')
```

In the console I get this:

```
Missing word: Football
football
wrong answer
football
wrong answer
```

Answer (score 1):

You must operate with `StringVar` instance e.g.:

```
        self.whatWord = StringVar()
        self.missingWordPrompt = Entry(root, textvariable=self.whatWord)
        self.missingWordPrompt.pack()

        self.submitbutton = Button(root, text='Check Answer', command=self.checkWord)
        self.submitbutton.pack()
def checkWord(self):
    self.answer = self.missingWord.get()
    self.my_input = self.whatWord.get()
    print(self.answer, self.my_input)

    if str(self.answer).strip().lower() == self.my_input.strip().lower():
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('wrong answer')
```

Read [this manual](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) about `Tkinter.Entry()`